# NServiceBus Issue On Updating version

Tags: nservicebus

I was trying to update an application that uses NServiceBus 2.0.0.1145 to 2.5.0.1446 , but when i started the application i am getting the following exception

```
FATAL NServiceBus.Host.Internal.GenericHost [(null)]
 - StructureMap.StructureMapException: StructureMap Exception Code:  207
Internal exception while creating Instance '19f293a7-8f99-4e87-b670-5083f8297fec
' of PluginType NServiceBus.IStartableBus, NServiceBus, Version=2.5.0.1446, Cult
ure=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9fc386479f8a226c.  Check the inner exception for mor
e details. ---> StructureMap.StructureMapException: StructureMap Exception Code:
  207
Internal exception while creating Instance '2155d2b3-df42-493b-a893-d80db8c77d60
' of PluginType NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.ITransport, NServiceBus.Core, Vers
ion=2.5.0.1446, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9fc386479f8a226c.  Check the inn
er exception for more details. ---> StructureMap.StructureMapException: Structur
eMap Exception Code:  207
Internal exception while creating Instance '628f6283-6f33-4d61-8dd8-d6e2e75c7779
' of PluginType NServiceBus.Serialization.IMessageSerializer, NServiceBus, Versi
on=2.5.0.1446, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9fc386479f8a226c.  Check the inne
r exception for more details. ---> StructureMap.StructureMapException: Structure
Map Exception Code:  207
Internal exception while creating Instance '32bd9546-42f3-41a3-9459-45591704c2cc
' of PluginType NServiceBus.Serializers.XML.MessageSerializer.  Check the inner
exception for more details. ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be n
ull.
Parameter name: con
   at System.Reflection.Emit.CustomAttributeBuilder.InitCustomAttributeBuilder(C
onstructorInfo con, Object[] constructorArgs, PropertyInfo[] namedProperties, Ob
ject[] propertyValues, FieldInfo[] namedFields, Object[] fieldValues)
   at System.Reflection.Emit.CustomAttributeBuilder..ctor(ConstructorInfo con, O
bject[] constructorArgs)
   at NServiceBus.MessageInterfaces.MessageMapper.Reflection.MessageMapper.AddCu
stomAttributeToProperty(Object customAttribute, PropertyBuilder propBuilder) in
d:\BuildAgent-02\work\20b5f701adefe8f8\src\impl\messageInterfaces\NServiceBus.Me
ssageInterfaces.MessageMapper.Reflection\MessageMapper.cs:line 211
   at NServiceBus.MessageInterfaces.MessageMapper.Reflection.MessageMapper.Creat
eTypeFrom(Type t, ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder) in d:\BuildAgent-02\work\20b5f701
adefe8f8\src\impl\messageInterfaces\NServiceBus.MessageInterfaces.MessageMapper.
Reflection\MessageMapper.cs:line 158
   at NServiceBus.MessageInterfaces.MessageMapper.Reflection.MessageMapper.Gener
ateImplementationFor(Type interfaceType, ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder) in d:\Buil
dAgent-02\work\20b5f701adefe8f8\src\impl\messageInterfaces\NServiceBus.MessageIn
terfaces.MessageMapper.Reflection\MessageMapper.cs:line 98
   at NServiceBus.MessageInterfaces.MessageMapper.Reflection.MessageMapper.InitT
ype(Type t, ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder) in d:\BuildAgent-02\work\20b5f701adefe8
f8\src\impl\messageInterfaces\NServiceBus.MessageInterfaces.MessageMapper.Reflec
tion\MessageMapper.cs:line 76
   at NServiceBus.MessageInterfaces.MessageMapper.Reflection.MessageMapper.Initi
alize(IEnumerable`1 types) in d:\BuildAgent-02\work\20b5f701adefe8f8\src\impl\me
ssageInterfaces\NServiceBus.MessageInterfaces.MessageMapper.Reflection\MessageMa
pper.cs:line 37
   at NServiceBus.Serializers.XML.MessageSerializer.set_MessageTypes(List`1 valu
e) in d:\BuildAgent-02\work\20b5f701adefe8f8\src\impl\Serializers\NServiceBus.Se
rializers.XML\MessageSerializer.cs:line 70
   at NServiceBusSerializersXMLMessageSerializerInstanceBuildera71d199d1ac44181b
9d8ee38416ba70b.BuildInstance(IConfiguredInstance , BuildSession )
   at StructureMap.Pipeline.ConfiguredInstanceBase`1.StructureMap.Pipeline.IConf
iguredInstance.Build(Type pluginType, BuildSession session, InstanceBuilder buil
der) in d:\dev\structuremap\Source\StructureMap\Pipeline\ConfiguredInstanceBase.
cs:line 105
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at StructureMap.Pipeline.ConfiguredInstanceBase`1.StructureMap.Pipeline.IConf
iguredInstance.Build(Type pluginType, BuildSession session, InstanceBuilder buil
der) in d:\dev\structuremap\Source\StructureMap\Pipeline\ConfiguredInstanceBase.
cs:line 117
   at StructureMap.Pipeline.ConfiguredInstanceBase`1.build(Type pluginType, Buil
dSession session) in d:\dev\structuremap\Source\StructureMap\Pipeline\Configured
InstanceBase.cs:line 166
   at StructureMap.Pipeline.Instance.createRawObject(Type pluginType, BuildSessi
on session) in d:\dev\structuremap\Source\StructureMap\Pipeline\Instance.cs:line
 140
   at StructureMap.Pipeline.Instance.Build(Type pluginType, BuildSession session
) in d:\dev\structuremap\Source\StructureMap\Pipeline\Instance.cs:line 106
   at StructureMap.Pipeline.ObjectBuilder.ConstructNew(Type pluginType, Instance
 instance, BuildSession session) in d:\dev\structuremap\Source\StructureMap\Pipe
line\ObjectBuilder.cs:line 41
   at StructureMap.Pipeline.ObjectBuilder.Resolve(Type pluginType, Instance inst
ance, BuildSession session) in d:\dev\structuremap\Source\StructureMap\Pipeline\
ObjectBuilder.cs:line 29
   at StructureMap.BuildSession.CreateInstance(Type pluginType, Instance instanc
e) in d:\dev\structuremap\Source\StructureMap\BuildSession.cs:line 143
   at StructureMap.BuildSession.<>c__DisplayClass3.<.ctor>b__1() in d:\dev\struc
turemap\Source\StructureMap\BuildSession.cs:line 32
   at StructureMap.BuildSession.CreateInstance(Type pluginType) in d:\dev\struct
uremap\Source\StructureMap\BuildSession.cs:line 177
   at StructureMap.BuildSession.StructureMap.IContext.GetInstance[T]() in d:\dev
\structuremap\Source\StructureMap\BuildSession.cs:line 80
   at NServiceBus.ObjectBuilder.StructureMap.StructureMapExtensions.Registration
`2.<RegisterServiceInterface>b__0(IContext ctx)
   at StructureMap.Pipeline.ConstructorInstance`1.build(Type pluginType, BuildSe
ssion session) in d:\dev\structuremap\Source\StructureMap\Pipeline\ConstructorIn
stance.cs:line 28
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at StructureMap.Pipeline.ConstructorInstance`1.build(Type pluginType, BuildSe
ssion session) in d:\dev\structuremap\Source\StructureMap\Pipeline\ConstructorIn
stance.cs:line 32
   at StructureMap.Pipeline.Instance.createRawObject(Type pluginType, BuildSessi
on session) in d:\dev\structuremap\Source\StructureMap\Pipeline\Instance.cs:line
 140
   at StructureMap.Pipeline.Instance.Build(Type pluginType, BuildSession session
) in d:\dev\structuremap\Source\StructureMap\Pipeline\Instance.cs:line 106
   at StructureMap.Pipeline.ObjectBuilder.ConstructNew(Type pluginType, Instance
 instance, BuildSession session) in d:\dev\structuremap\Source\StructureMap\Pipe
line\ObjectBuilder.cs:line 41
   at StructureMap.Pipeline.ObjectBuilder.Resolve(Type pluginType, Instance inst
ance, BuildSession session) in d:\dev\structuremap\Source\StructureMap\Pipeline\
ObjectBuilder.cs:line 29
   at StructureMap.BuildSession.CreateInstance(Type pluginType, Instance instanc
e) in d:\dev\structuremap\Source\StructureMap\BuildSession.cs:line 143
   at StructureMap.BuildSession.<>c__DisplayClass3.<.ctor>b__1() in d:\dev\struc
turemap\Source\StructureMap\BuildSession.cs:line 32
   at StructureMap.BuildSession.CreateInstance(Type pluginType) in d:\dev\struct
uremap\Source\StructureMap\BuildSession.cs:line 177
   at StructureMap.Pipeline.DefaultInstance.build(Type pluginType, BuildSession
session) in d:\dev\structuremap\Source\StructureMap\Pipeline\DefaultInstance.cs:
line 14
   at StructureMap.Pipeline.Instance.createRawObject(Type pluginType, BuildSessi
on session) in d:\dev\structuremap\Source\StructureMap\Pipeline\Instance.cs:line
 140
   at StructureMap.Pipeline.Instance.Build(Type pluginType, BuildSession session
) in d:\dev\structuremap\Source\StructureMap\Pipeline\Instance.cs:line 106
   at StructureMap.Pipeline.ConfiguredInstanceBase`1.getChild(String propertyNam
e, Type pluginType, BuildSession buildSession) in d:\dev\structuremap\Source\Str
uctureMap\Pipeline\ConfiguredInstanceBase.cs:line 176
   at StructureMap.Pipeline.ConfiguredInstanceBase`1.StructureMap.Pipeline.IConf
iguredInstance.GetChild(String propertyName, Type pluginType, BuildSession build
Session) in d:\dev\structuremap\Source\StructureMap\Pipeline\ConfiguredInstanceB
ase.cs:line 91
   at NServiceBusUnicastTransportMsmqMsmqTransportInstanceBuilder1e093241493b413
4b568f6092322262b.BuildInstance(IConfiguredInstance , BuildSession )
   at StructureMap.Pipeline.ConfiguredInstanceBase`1.StructureMap.Pipeline.IConf
iguredInstance.Build(Type pluginType, BuildSession session, InstanceBuilder buil
der) in d:\dev\structuremap\Source\StructureMap\Pipeline\ConfiguredInstanceBase.
cs:line 109
   at StructureMap.Pipeline.ConfiguredInstanceBase`1.build(Type pluginType, Buil
dSession session) in d:\dev\structuremap\Source\StructureMap\Pipeline\Configured
InstanceBase.cs:line 166
   at StructureMap.Pipeline.Instance.createRawObject(Type pluginType, BuildSessi
on session) in d:\dev\structuremap\Source\StructureMap\Pipeline\Instance.cs:line
 140
   at StructureMap.Pipeline.Instance.Build(Type pluginType, BuildSession session
) in d:\dev\structuremap\Source\StructureMap\Pipeline\Instance.cs:line 106
   at StructureMap.Pipeline.ObjectBuilder.ConstructNew(Type pluginType, Instance
 instance, BuildSession session) in d:\dev\structuremap\Source\StructureMap\Pipe
line\ObjectBuilder.cs:line 41
   at StructureMap.Pipeline.ObjectBuilder.Resolve(Type pluginType, Instance inst
ance, BuildSession session) in d:\dev\structuremap\Source\StructureMap\Pipeline\
ObjectBuilder.cs:line 29
   at StructureMap.BuildSession.CreateInstance(Type pluginType, Instance instanc
e) in d:\dev\structuremap\Source\StructureMap\BuildSession.cs:line 143
   at StructureMap.BuildSession.<>c__DisplayClass3.<.ctor>b__1() in d:\dev\struc
turemap\Source\StructureMap\BuildSession.cs:line 32
   at StructureMap.BuildSession.CreateInstance(Type pluginType) in d:\dev\struct
uremap\Source\StructureMap\BuildSession.cs:line 177
   at StructureMap.BuildSession.StructureMap.IContext.GetInstance[T]() in d:\dev
\structuremap\Source\StructureMap\BuildSession.cs:line 80
   at NServiceBus.ObjectBuilder.StructureMap.StructureMapExtensions.Registration
`2.<RegisterServiceInterface>b__0(IContext ctx)
   at StructureMap.Pipeline.ConstructorInstance`1.build(Type pluginType, BuildSe
ssion session) in d:\dev\structuremap\Source\StructureMap\Pipeline\ConstructorIn
stance.cs:line 28
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at StructureMap.Pipeline.ConstructorInstance`1.build(Type pluginType, BuildSe
ssion session) in d:\dev\structuremap\Source\StructureMap\Pipeline\ConstructorIn
stance.cs:line 32
   at StructureMap.Pipeline.Instance.createRawObject(Type pluginType, BuildSessi
on session) in d:\dev\structuremap\Source\StructureMap\Pipeline\Instance.cs:line
 140
   at StructureMap.Pipeline.Instance.Build(Type pluginType, BuildSession session
) in d:\dev\structuremap\Source\StructureMap\Pipeline\Instance.cs:line 106
   at StructureMap.Pipeline.ObjectBuilder.ConstructNew(Type pluginType, Instance
 instance, BuildSession session) in d:\dev\structuremap\Source\StructureMap\Pipe
line\ObjectBuilder.cs:line 41
   at StructureMap.Pipeline.ObjectBuilder.Resolve(Type pluginType, Instance inst
ance, BuildSession session) in d:\dev\structuremap\Source\StructureMap\Pipeline\
ObjectBuilder.cs:line 29
   at StructureMap.BuildSession.CreateInstance(Type pluginType, Instance instanc
e) in d:\dev\structuremap\Source\StructureMap\BuildSession.cs:line 143
   at StructureMap.BuildSession.<>c__DisplayClass3.<.ctor>b__1() in d:\dev\struc
turemap\Source\StructureMap\BuildSession.cs:line 32
   at StructureMap.BuildSession.CreateInstance(Type pluginType) in d:\dev\struct
uremap\Source\StructureMap\BuildSession.cs:line 177
   at StructureMap.Pipeline.DefaultInstance.build(Type pluginType, BuildSession
session) in d:\dev\structuremap\Source\StructureMap\Pipeline\DefaultInstance.cs:
line 14
   at StructureMap.Pipeline.Instance.createRawObject(Type pluginType, BuildSessi
on session) in d:\dev\structuremap\Source\StructureMap\Pipeline\Instance.cs:line
 140
   at StructureMap.Pipeline.Instance.Build(Type pluginType, BuildSession session
) in d:\dev\structuremap\Source\StructureMap\Pipeline\Instance.cs:line 106
   at StructureMap.Pipeline.ConfiguredInstanceBase`1.getChild(String propertyNam
e, Type pluginType, BuildSession buildSession) in d:\dev\structuremap\Source\Str
uctureMap\Pipeline\ConfiguredInstanceBase.cs:line 176
   at StructureMap.Pipeline.ConfiguredInstanceBase`1.StructureMap.Pipeline.IConf
iguredInstance.GetChild(String propertyName, Type pluginType, BuildSession build
Session) in d:\dev\structuremap\Source\StructureMap\Pipeline\ConfiguredInstanceB
ase.cs:line 91
   at NServiceBusUnicastUnicastBusInstanceBuilderb0bf705c932c4e979e9826afc26acef
4.BuildInstance(IConfiguredInstance , BuildSession )
   at StructureMap.Pipeline.ConfiguredInstanceBase`1.StructureMap.Pipeline.IConf
iguredInstance.Build(Type pluginType, BuildSession session, InstanceBuilder buil
der) in d:\dev\structuremap\Source\StructureMap\Pipeline\ConfiguredInstanceBase.
cs:line 109
   at StructureMap.Pipeline.ConfiguredInstanceBase`1.build(Type pluginType, Buil
dSession session) in d:\dev\structuremap\Source\StructureMap\Pipeline\Configured
InstanceBase.cs:line 166
   at StructureMap.Pipeline.Instance.createRawObject(Type pluginType, BuildSessi
on session) in d:\dev\structuremap\Source\StructureMap\Pipeline\Instance.cs:line
 140
   at StructureMap.Pipeline.Instance.Build(Type pluginType, BuildSession session
) in d:\dev\structuremap\Source\StructureMap\Pipeline\Instance.cs:line 106
   at StructureMap.Pipeline.ObjectBuilder.ConstructNew(Type pluginType, Instance
 instance, BuildSession session) in d:\dev\structuremap\Source\StructureMap\Pipe
line\ObjectBuilder.cs:line 41
   at StructureMap.Pipeline.ObjectBuilder.Resolve(Type pluginType, Instance inst
ance, BuildSession session) in d:\dev\structuremap\Source\StructureMap\Pipeline\
ObjectBuilder.cs:line 29
   at StructureMap.BuildSession.CreateInstance(Type pluginType, Instance instanc
e) in d:\dev\structuremap\Source\StructureMap\BuildSession.cs:line 143
   at StructureMap.BuildSession.<>c__DisplayClass3.<.ctor>b__1() in d:\dev\struc
turemap\Source\StructureMap\BuildSession.cs:line 32
   at StructureMap.BuildSession.CreateInstance(Type pluginType) in d:\dev\struct
uremap\Source\StructureMap\BuildSession.cs:line 177
   at StructureMap.BuildSession.StructureMap.IContext.GetInstance[T]() in d:\dev
\structuremap\Source\StructureMap\BuildSession.cs:line 80
   at NServiceBus.ObjectBuilder.StructureMap.StructureMapExtensions.Registration
`2.<RegisterServiceInterface>b__0(IContext ctx)
   at StructureMap.Pipeline.ConstructorInstance`1.build(Type pluginType, BuildSe
ssion session) in d:\dev\structuremap\Source\StructureMap\Pipeline\ConstructorIn
stance.cs:line 28
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at StructureMap.Pipeline.ConstructorInstance`1.build(Type pluginType, BuildSe
ssion session) in d:\dev\structuremap\Source\StructureMap\Pipeline\ConstructorIn
stance.cs:line 32
   at StructureMap.Pipeline.Instance.createRawObject(Type pluginType, BuildSessi
on session) in d:\dev\structuremap\Source\StructureMap\Pipeline\Instance.cs:line
 140
   at StructureMap.Pipeline.Instance.Build(Type pluginType, BuildSession session
) in d:\dev\structuremap\Source\StructureMap\Pipeline\Instance.cs:line 106
   at StructureMap.Pipeline.ObjectBuilder.ConstructNew(Type pluginType, Instance
 instance, BuildSession session) in d:\dev\structuremap\Source\StructureMap\Pipe
line\ObjectBuilder.cs:line 41
   at StructureMap.Pipeline.ObjectBuilder.Resolve(Type pluginType, Instance inst
ance, BuildSession session) in d:\dev\structuremap\Source\StructureMap\Pipeline\
ObjectBuilder.cs:line 29
   at StructureMap.BuildSession.CreateInstance(Type pluginType, Instance instanc
e) in d:\dev\structuremap\Source\StructureMap\BuildSession.cs:line 143
   at StructureMap.BuildSession.<>c__DisplayClass3.<.ctor>b__1() in d:\dev\struc
turemap\Source\StructureMap\BuildSession.cs:line 32
   at StructureMap.BuildSession.CreateInstance(Type pluginType) in d:\dev\struct
uremap\Source\StructureMap\BuildSession.cs:line 177
   at StructureMap.Container.GetInstance(Type pluginType) in d:\dev\structuremap
\Source\StructureMap\Container.cs:line 256
   at StructureMap.Container.TryGetInstance(Type pluginType) in d:\dev\structure
map\Source\StructureMap\Container.cs:line 208
   at NServiceBus.ObjectBuilder.StructureMap.StructureMapObjectBuilder.NServiceB
us.ObjectBuilder.Common.IContainer.Build(Type typeToBuild)
   at NServiceBus.ObjectBuilder.Common.CommonObjectBuilder.NServiceBus.ObjectBui
lder.IBuilder.Build[T]() in d:\BuildAgent-02\work\20b5f701adefe8f8\src\impl\Obje
ctBuilder.Common\ObjectBuilder.Common\CommonObjectBuilder.cs:line 93
   at NServiceBus.Host.Internal.GenericHost.Start() in d:\BuildAgent-02\work\20b
5f701adefe8f8\src\host\NServiceBus.Host\Internal\GenericHost.cs:line 75
```

When looking at one of the link in net (http://tech.dir.groups.yahoo.com/group/nservicebus/message/7520) i got info like there seems some issue with structuremap 2.5.4.0 but when i tried to update 2.6.2.0 it says version 2.5.4 is missing which means the nservicebis internally uses 2.5.4.0.
So could you please let me know whatr needs to be done?

Thanks,
Ajai

Comment: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be n
ull.
Parameter name: con
   at System.Reflection.Emit.CustomAttributeBuilder.InitCustomAttributeBuilder(C
onstructorInfo con, Object[] constructorArgs, PropertyInfo[] namedProperties, Ob
ject[] propertyValues, FieldInfo[] namedFields, Object[] fieldValues)
   at System.Reflection.Emit.CustomAttributeBuilder..ctor(ConstructorInfo con, O
bject[] constructorArgs)  Something seems to be wrong with one of you message classes /interfaces. Can you post them here?

Comment: this is working with older versions of the nservicebus with the same internal messages

Answer (score 1):

Just for pure diagnostics, try pulling down the source code for NServiceBus, put v2.6.2.0 of StructureMap into the libraries folder (over the top of the old StructureMap assembly), and then run the following:

.\tools\nant\nant package

After about 2-5 minutes (depending upon your system), this will produce an NServiceBus "package" that you can extract and reference.

If that solves the problem, we can look at permanently upgrading the 2.5 branch to use the later StructureMap assembly.